# Is there built-in alternative to google analytics in Liferay

Tags: google-analytics, liferay

I'm looking for a portlet like-solution that would collect and report usage analytics in Liferay... but google analytics is not an option, unfortunately.

Stats by community, group, session tracking, apart from the usual bounce and exit rates, referrals, origin, etc. I know I'm kind of asking the reinvention of the wheel, but there are plenty of usage data that can be collected by Liferay that google can't. I've already checked [PiWik](http://piwik.org/), and it looks very impressive.

Any suggestions? TIA,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of 2015 there is Audience Targeting plugin, which (at least for Liferay 6.2) comes bundled with analytics-api / analytics-hook modules, which collect some useful analytics data. Mind now:

1. So far it doesn't look like there is any *standalone* use for them as they were introduced, I believe, to enable the *content visited*, *page visited* and other such rules in the Audience Targeting itself; you can't see the raw events in any of the provided portlets
2. The events are stored as rows in a SQL database, so I would be concerned about it's performance in the long run (with thousands of clicks every minute etc.), although I say this purely theoretically as I haven't done any tests myself nor checked if there are some performance enhancing measures implemented

What you can do, however, is to put together your own portlet which would create some graphs etc. based on the data stored in `CT_Analytics_AnalyticsEvent` table.

Comment: As of 2015 / Liferay 6.2, even Piwik integration no longer is a 3rd party add on but comes fully integrated in Liferay. I kind of like it better than having the portlet write access statistics itself, as it totally separates the write operations from delivering the content (which would otherwise inherently be read-only). But I understand that Analytics/Audience Targetting actually makes better use of this data. Good that you thought about updating this ancient post.

Answer (score 2):

Right now, I dont think there is any out of the box feature available for this, you might need to create this. There can be 2 things

1) You need to create a javascript library if you need realtime/web analysis (this is same like creating google analytics lib)

2) This option is quite easy. Liferay stores everything in db, you can have a report portlet which will show the report based on the data. We did this for one project where we were tracking the session ids/ip and logged in user details for portlets.

To achieve point 2) you can create new Liferay service, which will be used to store these data and retrieve.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Felix and Olaf for the responses, sorry for the delay in my response.

To me the second option just seemed more feasible, I mean, liferay already gets all the requests, so it should be simple enough to store the request data and produce the stats. Then again, if it were that easy, someone would've done it by now... what Am I missing?

Comment: What are you missing? Well both are valid ways to solve the problem. An external solution can scale independently of the main server. Having an additional database-write transaction can be prohibitive on high-traffic servers, while just adding references to external systems adds a lot less overhead on the server side.

Answer (score 2):

You already mention Piwik, which is similar to google analytics. You probably have your own theme (almost everybody changes the appearance to look like their own site) and it's quite appropriate to place the relevant piwik-stats-snippet in there.

You can also, as Felix suggests, mine your log files. Liferay stores some data, your webserver access logs also are quite worth to mine. And, of course, you can change your theme to log even more for every page access, just take care that you don't create a performance bottleneck by writing too much during one page request.

So, coming back to your question: Built-in like google analytics: No. Easily integrateable (like Piwik): Yes, of course. Completely customizeable: Yes, of course.

Edit: It just happens that David has [created and documented an integration](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Adding+Piwik+Web+Analytics+to+Liferay) that makes using Piwik even easier